# Using pg_dump with huge # of tables?

Tags: postgresql

I'm dealing with a database system that can have thousands of tables.  The problem is, when I try to back it up using `pg_dump`, I sometimes get the following error:

```
pg_dump: WARNING:  out of shared memory
pg_dump: SQL command failed
pg_dump: Error message from server: ERROR:  out of shared memory
HINT:  You might need to increase max_locks_per_transaction.
pg_dump: The command was: LOCK TABLE public.foo IN ACCESS SHARE MODE
```

I could of course increase the `max_locks_per_transaction` setting.  But the problem is that the number of tables can vary.  I don't want to constantly have to revisit this setting every time there is a failure (assuming we notice the failure at all, given that this is in a cron job!).

What would be the best way to tackle this problem?  Currently I'm working on a Perl script that will list all the tables and then call `pg_dump` in "chunks" to keep a limit on the number of table locks, but I bet I could do better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a consistent backup, you must increase the max_locks_per_transaction.

Doing it in chunks from a script will make the backup *inconsistent* if you have concurrent access, which is probably not what you want.

Your other option is to use PITR and do a filesystem level backup. That will not take out any locks at all in the database.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  I am checking out PITR right now.  I will point out, however, that I am fortunate -- these tables are mostly write-only, so consistency is not an issue.

Comment: Sorry, make that "write-once" :-).